# Get all options from Select Tag in Robot Framework

Tags: for-loop, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, robotframework, select-options

I want to get all options from Select tag & then iterate over the options to match the criteria & then select that option. Something like this:
${option_I_want}
@{list_from_select_options}

```
FOR    ${each_option}    IN    @{list_from_select_options}
    IF    ${option_I_want} == ${each_option}
        select from list by label    ${each_option}
        BREAK
    ELSE
        Log    Not found
    END
END
```

I tried taking all options of select by xpath, like :
xpath=//select[@id='someId']/option
But I'm not getting all option values.